# How do I change visibility settings in Visual Studio 2017 using C++

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++-cx

I'm trying to make a button visible then invisible with a button click, but I am new to windows coding so any help would be helpful.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace App1;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at 
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409
int blockbase = 1 ;
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
void App1::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, 
Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    greetingOutput->Text = "Hello, " + nameInput->Text + "! \n Welcome to the 
    worlds worst quiz show!!! \n Here is the one and only question: What 
    director directed the classic film Battleship Potempkin?";

    AnswerChoiceA-> Visibility = "Visible" ;
}
```

Currently I am getting errors C2664 and E1767
C2664:'void Windows::UI::Xaml::UIElement::Visibility::set(Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [8]' to 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility'

E1767: function "Windows::UI::Xaml::UIElement::Visibility::set" cannot be called with the given argument list

Comment: 1) This is C++/CLI, **not** C++. Please tag accordingly. 2) "_Currently I am getting errors C2664 and E1767_" I don't know about you, but, we, typically, don't go about remembering error codes. Copy-paste full error messages.

Comment: Changed to your suggestions

Comment: In that case: did you try reading the documentation of [`UIElement.Visibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility)? Hint: it's type is not string, as you are trying to treat it, like it is.

Comment: It is just a simple mistake, the Visibility property does not accept a string.  The error message is pretty explicit, you need to use the Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility enum type.  So simply Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible here.